# how to make zappajs to handle all requests

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, express, zappa

There is `app.all` for express to handle all methods for any endpoint like this

```
app.all '*', (req, res) ->
    # code goes here
```

I could not find equivalent one for zappa. It throws error if I try `@all`. 
What is the equivalent on in zappajs?

Comment: checked zappajs code and issues in github project. They seem to fixed it but not yet available with npm!

Answer (score 0):

This is working on my Zappa 0.4.12 server:

```
@all '*': ->
    console.log( "all requests" )
```